# Integrate: $\int\limits_0^{2\pi } {\exp \left( {ar\cos ({\psi _a} - \theta ) + b{r^2}\cos ({\psi _b} - \theta )....} \right)} d\theta $?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, bessel-functions

I am trying to find the following integral in the close form:

$\int\limits_0^{2\pi } {\exp \left( {ar\cos ({\psi _a} - \theta ) + b{r^2}\cos ({\psi _b} - \theta ) + c{r^3}\cos ({\psi _c} - \theta )} \right)} d\theta $

Where, $a,b,c,r$ is non-negative real number.

I was trying to use the form of zero-order modified Bessel identity that is,
Assuming $a > 0$,
$$ I_0(x) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi e^{x\cos\theta}d\theta $$
Where $I_0(x)$ is a modified Bessel function of the first kind.

My approach:

1. Converting ${ar\cos ({\psi _a} - \theta ) + b{r^2}\cos ({\psi _b} - \theta ) + c{r^3}\cos ({\psi _c} - \theta )}=Kcos({\psi _K}-\theta)$. Then use the identity mentioned above. But I am not sure if it is possible to convert ${ar\cos ({\psi _a} - \theta ) + b{r^2}\cos ({\psi _b} - \theta ) + c{r^3}\cos ({\psi _c} - \theta )}=Kcos({\psi _K}-\theta)$?
2. Is there any other approach that I might take? Any suggestion would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I shall try to make it completely general.

Changing notations, the agument of the exponential function is
$$S=\sum_{n=1}^p a_n r^n \cos (\psi_n-\theta) $$ Expanding the cosines, we have
$$S=\Big[\sum_{n=1}^p a_n r^n \cos (\psi_n)\Big]\cos (\theta)+\Big[\sum_{n=1}^p a_n r^n \sin (\psi_n)\Big]\sin (\theta)$$ that is to say
$$S=A_c \,\cos (\theta)+A_s \,\sin (\theta)$$ and then the problem is
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \exp\Big[A_c \,\cos (\theta)+A_s \,\sin (\theta)\Big]\,d\theta=2 \pi  I_0\left(\sqrt{A_c^2+A_s^2}\right)$$

Comment: This is so beautiful. Thank you.

Comment: @Samantha. You are welcome !